# Provisional Patent Application Cover Sheet Error

Tags: provisional-application

I recently submitted a provisional patent application but I realized that I accidentally checked a box "Application Data Sheet" on the cover sheet even though I did not include it on my submissions. Will this create any delays or require me to send a new coversheet with a fee?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to refile but you should probably file the ADS that you indicated was originally included. There should not be any fee for this.